# Why Akhira should be our priority?

Tags: akhirah

Why we need to concentrate more on the life of Hereafter than this world?

Comment: A one liner is a bad choice for a question as it doesn't show any prior research effort!

Comment: The question detail is mentioned below the title that is Why we need to concentrate more on the life of Hereafter than this world?

Answer (score 2):

Sahl bin Sa'd narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said:

> ***“What is the world compared to the Hereafter but as a needle dipped into the waters of the ocean?”***
> (Al-Mu’jam al-Kabīr:17148)

Prophet Muhammad PBUH further says:

> that the importance of this world to Allah Subhan Tallah is ***like a dead lamb*** (Sahih Muslim: 2957a, Riyad as Salihin: 463) and ***less than a fly wing.*** (Tirmidhi: 2320).

It has been related by Mustawrid (R.A.) that the Prophet (S.A.W.) said:

> ***"By Allah, this world (i.e., its pleasures and duration) in comparison with the Hereafter is (similar to the amount of water) one gets when he puts his finger in the sea. Let him then see what it returns with."***
> (Sahih Muslim:2858, Ibn Majah: 4108).

Our wants and desires are unlimited for this world and we live here as if we will never die so soon. That’s why, we are so busy getting the best of everything, i.e., best company to work at, best house to live in, best means to enjoy life to its maximum, etc.
**But what about the best Akhira?**

Which contains:

> **“And when you look there [in Paradise] you will see a delight (that cannot be imagined), and a Realm Magnificent.”** (Insan: 20).

However, it does not mean that you ignore or leave this world altogether because Allah has made Muslims a balanced nation **اُمَّةً وَّسَطًا/ امتِ معتدل** (Baqarah:143) the ones who maintain a balance between their outlook towards this world and the hereafter.

It was narrated from Abu Dharr Al-Ghifari that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:

> ***“Indifference towards this world does not mean forbidding what is permitted, or squandering wealth, rather indifference towards this world means not thinking that what you have in your hand is more reliable than what is in Allah’s Hand, and it means feeling that the reward for a calamity that befalls you is greater than that which the calamity makes you miss out on”*** (Ibn Majah: 4100, Dai’f).

Have you ever seen a student who takes examination hall as a picnic point? No, all students behave seriously and worried about their paper, upon which their success and future depends. Same is the case here:

> ***“Indeed, We have made that which is on the earth adornment for it that We may test them [as to] which of them is best in deed”***
> (Kahf: 7).

Irrespective of the fact, that the hereafter life is the real life and this world is only a means to prepare us for this true life. To what extent we are serious about the answer sheet of our Ammal, upon which our future (Akhira) depends.

Prophet Muhammad ﷺ said:

> ***'What do I have to do with the world! I am not in the world but as a rider seeking shade under a tree, then he catches his breath and leaves it.'"***
> (Tirmidhi: 2377),

It was narrated that Ibn ‘Umar said:

> ***“The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) took hold of some part of my body and said: ‘O ‘Abdullah, be in this world like a stranger, or one who is passing through, and consider yourself as one of the people of the graves.’”***
> (Ibn Majah: 4114),

> ***"Paradise and Hell were presented to me and I have never seen the good and evil as (I did) today. And if you were to know you would have wept more and laughed less..."***
> (Sahih Muslim: 2359a).

> ***"But you prefer the worldly life. Even though the Hereafter is far batter and more lasting"***
> (Ala: 16,17).

and

> ***"You merely seek the gains of the world whereas Allah desires (for you the good) of the Hereafter."***
> (Anfal: 67).

We all need to think that for whom we have more love? is it for the worldly success or the success in the hereafter?

> ***"Say, ˹O Prophet, If your parents and children and siblings and spouses and extended family and the wealth you have acquired and the trade you fear will decline and the homes you cherish—˹if all these˺ are more beloved to you than Allah and His Messenger and struggling in His Way, then wait until Allah brings about His Will. Allah does not guide the rebellious people"***
> (Taubah: 24).

So, have you prepared enough to survive in the ocean of Akhira or all of your endeavors are for the needle like world?

**Think for a moment.**